# How to integrate Gatsby with NodeJs Express Backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, gatsby

I have Gatsby as my frontend and NodeJs/Express to fetch API data. I edited gatsby-config.js with the following

```
module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */

  proxy: {
    prefix: "/api",
    url: "http://localhost:4000",
  },
}
```

to make this work.

It works in my development environment, but not when I run the gatsby production build. When I run the gatsby production build and go to the live production website, the nodeJS API data is not being fetched. I'm I missing a build step.

I do

gatsby build

gatsby serve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/api-proxy/#proxying-api-requests-in-development):

> Keep in mind that proxy only has effect in development (with gatsby
>   develop), and it is up to you to ensure that URLs like /api/todos
>   point to the right place in production.

In production, you need to send your HTML requests directly to your backend server without a proxy. Use a library like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios):

Here an example from the axios repo for a POST request:

```
// Send a POST request
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```

You will run into a CORS block by your browser. Your backend needs to set the right response header so your browser will accept the response. In your express app set the cors:

```
const Express = require("express");
const BodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = Express();
app.use(BodyParser.text({ type: "text/plain" }));

/* CORS */
// app.use(cors()); // Enable cors for all origins
app.use(cors({
  /** Use this when web frontend / production **/
  // origin: 'https://example.com',

  /** Use this when local frontend / development **/
  origin: "http://localhost:8000",
}));
```

Comment: When I build for production what changes do I make to package.json ?

Comment: For Gatsby: Nothing. For Express: yarn add express body-parser cors

Comment: So when I want to build both for production I just run Gatsby build and npm start? When I do that, Gatsby doesn’t recognize node backend but it does in development

Comment: I don't know enough about your setup to answer your question. You might want to create another post for this new question.

Comment: I have then express files in the root directory. Then in client directory I have the gatsby files. In gatsby-config.js I have the following code

`module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */

  proxy: {
    prefix: "/api",
    url: "http://localhost:4000",
  }
}`

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with this setup. =(

Comment: @PotaOnasys It sounds like you don't need to use proxy here. The proxy setting is meant for cases where you're fetching data from resources living in the same domain, i.e Gatsby lives at `mysite.com` and your api is at `mysite.com/api/posts`.

You should instead set your backend url as an environment variable & ensure it's pointed to the correct url of your deployed server in production. If you're only doing `gatsby build` locally, then you don't need to set env, just use your localhost url directly.